# How can I specify the number of decimal places of a BigDecimal to print?

Tags: java, bigdecimal

I am using `BigDecimal` as follows:

```
BigDecimal val = object.getValue();//it returns BigDecimal type value
```

`val` contains 12.2300. I want to display 12.23 on my page. How can I do this?

Comment: Possible dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3395825/how-to-print-formatted-bigdecimal-values

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`DecimalFormat`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html):

```
String formatted = new DecimalFormat("#.##").format(val);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use DecimalFormat or you can manipulate it with String operations

```
        public static String format(BigDecimal big, int precision){
            String bigS = big.toString();
            int index = bigS.indexOf('.');
            String add = bigS.substring(index, index + precision + 1);
            String formatted = big.longValue() + "" + add;

            return formatted;
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            BigDecimal big = new BigDecimal(2342342232.23232);
            System.out.println(format(big, 2));
            System.out.println(format(big, 3));
        }
```

Of course, DecimalFormat is clever way

Comment: One should not rely on `toString()` at all. ;)