# android big decimal approximation

Tags: android, numbers, bigdecimal

I want to approximate a number showing only two digits after the decimal point.
I wrote this:

```
String result = String.valueOf(new BigDecimal(price).setScale(4, BigDecimal.ROUND_UP).doubleValue());
```

If `price` is a decimal number like `63,9222`, it works fine. But If `price` is ,for example, equal to `7.00`, is printed `7.0` .

I tried to use `RoundingMode.CEILING` instead of `BigDecimal.ROUND_UP` , but it didn't work and i don't know why. Maybe it will be better to use Double instead of BigDecimal?

Comment: Have you tried `ROUND_CEILING`?

Comment: Use NumberFormat to avoid all that hassle: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3395825/how-to-print-formatted-bigdecimal-values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `String.format`

```
double myValue = new BigDecimal(price).setScale(4, BigDecimal.ROUND_UP).doubleValue());
String result = String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "%.2f", myValue);
```