# Format Java BigDecimal as currency with 0 or 2 decimal places

Tags: java, string, formatting, currency

In my app, I need to format a BigDecimal object as a String that looks like currency.

E.g. I need:

- 45.50 to come out as $45.50
- 3.444 to come out as $3.44
- 0.199 to come out as $0.20
- **6.0 to come out as $6**
- 1200 to come out as $1,200

**In other words, I want to show a max of 2 decimal places and a minimum of 0 decimal places (and never just 1 decimal place).**

And the rounding should be the usual way, where 0.0050 rounds to 0.01 and 0.0049 rounds to 0.

Thanks!

P.S. I think my question differs from [How to print formatted BigDecimal values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3395825/how-to-print-formatted-bigdecimal-values) because I don't ever want to show .00 for whole numbers.

**2nd update:**

I can't believe people closed this as a duplicate and pointed to an answer that does NOT answer my question.  That type of person slowly chips away at the usefulness of StackOverflow.

**Here is an answer that I've come up with, but it feels ugly, and I encourage others to share better ideas:**

```
public static String getCasualDollarFormattedNumber(BigDecimal number)
{
    String showsTwoDecimalPlaces = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance().format(number);
    String zeroes = ".00";
    String lastCharacters = showsTwoDecimalPlaces.substring(Math.max(showsTwoDecimalPlaces.length() - zeroes
            .length(), 0));
    return (lastCharacters.equals(zeroes)) ? showsTwoDecimalPlaces.substring(0, 
            showsTwoDecimalPlaces.length() - zeroes.length()) : showsTwoDecimalPlaces;
}
```

Test:

```
@Test
public void testGetCasualDollarFormattedNumber()
{
    Assert.assertEquals(Replacer.getCasualDollarFormattedNumber(new BigDecimal(45.50)), "$45.50");
    Assert.assertEquals(Replacer.getCasualDollarFormattedNumber(new BigDecimal(3.444)), "$3.44");
    Assert.assertEquals(Replacer.getCasualDollarFormattedNumber(new BigDecimal(0.199)), "$0.20");
    Assert.assertEquals(Replacer.getCasualDollarFormattedNumber(new BigDecimal(6.0)), "$6");
    Assert.assertEquals(Replacer.getCasualDollarFormattedNumber(new BigDecimal(1200)), "$1,200");
}
```

Comment: I don't think so.  I think you didn't read the details of my question.  I updated it to make them stand out more.  Thanks!

Comment: @Ryan The change the `NumberFormatter`...The basic concept is the same

Comment: Why? It's an inconsistent requirement. It can be done but it requires extra code. Tell the designer it's simpler to just use 2 decimal places throughout.

Comment: There's nothing builtin.  Format it as already described and then truncate the last 3 characters if they're equal to `decimalFormat.getDecimalFormatSymbols().getDecimalSeparator() + "00"`

Comment: NumberFormat formatter = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
  formatter.setMinimumFractionDigits(0);
  formatter.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
  return formatter.format(number);