# How to keep two decimals even if the second decimal is a zero?

Tags: java, decimal, zero

So I use ...

```
System.out.printf("%.2f",variable);
```

and it works. But if the second decimal place is a `0`, it just ignores the zero and gives the answer to one decimal place. How can I get two decimal places including the zero?

Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java - always keep two decimal places even in zeroes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20463196/java-always-keep-two-decimal-places-even-in-zeroes)

Comment: Can't reproduce: https://ideone.com/OPSVhm. Can you make a [mre]?

Comment: `%.2f` should work. ["For the floating-point conversions 'a', 'A', 'e', 'E', and 'f' the precision is the number of digits after the radix point."](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Formatter.html)

Comment: 'System.out.printf("%.2f",2.0000); ' does print  '2.00' as expected. Se running code here: https://github.com/RobbingDaHood/answers/blob/master/so70838166/src/Main.java

Answer (score 0):

you can use DecimalFormat like this

```
DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("#0.00");
String format = decimalFormat.format(variable);
```

Comment: But what's the point, the code from the original question also works fine.