# How to convert Money to BigDecimal in Java?

Tags: java

How do I convert a variable of type Money to type BigDecimal in Java?

```
BigDecimal big = BigDecimal.valueOf(money);
```

Doesn't work.

Comment: `BigDecimal big = money.getAmount();`? (referring to this: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13166_01/alcs/docs51/javadoc/com/elasticpath/domain/misc/Money.html)

Comment: What "Money" type?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to print formatted BigDecimal values?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3395825/how-to-print-formatted-bigdecimal-values)

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"?

Comment: Why the down-votes, so I know for future reference?

Comment: @user3037540 Because you didn't say what doesn't work (although in this case it's pretty obvious), you didn't specify what kind of variable `Money` is, and it appears you didn't read the documentation for the `Money` class.

Comment: Please update your Q to reflect the which `Money` type you are referring to in the Q.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `Money` type is the one as suggested by [Alexis C.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1587046/zouzou) in a comment above, from the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13166_01/alcs/docs51/javadoc/com/elasticpath/domain/misc/Money.html#getAmount%28%29):

> **getAmount**
>
> java.math.BigDecimal getAmount()
>   Get the amount of money as a
>   BigDecimal.
>   Returns: the BigDecimal amount

So you should just call `BigDecimal big = money.getAmount();`

Otherwise if `Money` is a of a different type or your own custom class then to construct `BigDecimal` representation you need to call the appropriate `BigDecimal` constructor with the relevant `money` amount.

Simple example:

```
// Assume getAmount() returns a numerical primitive type i.e. int, double, long
BigDecimal big = new BigDecimal(money.getAmount());
```

There are a lot of different constructors so please see the `BigDecimal` [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html).