# BigDecimal to string conversion adds a zero before decimal point

Tags: java, string, bigdecimal

In my code, if I convert a string, for example

```
String str = ".12";
String str2 = "0.12"
```

to Bigdecimal, both gives me the output 0.12. My output requires me not to change the notation - is there a way I can have BigDecimal conversion from string in this case not add 0 to it for .12? I am okay when it keeps 0.12 to 0.12.

I just want the Bigdecimal to preserve the string input exactly the way it is, no adding of zeroes, no removing of zeroes.

I am doing this:

```
Bigdecimal bd = new Bigdecimal(str);
bd.toString() gives me 0.12
```

Comment: [Related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3395825/how-to-print-formatted-bigdecimal-values)

Comment: I have come to the conclusion that this can't be done using any formatting or using a function of Bigdecimal class. Only way I could find is to print out the original string. Still waiting for an answer though.

Comment: As you found out, BigDecimal can not be made *not* to output the single `0` in front of the decimal point. BigDecimal does not keep track of the original string, so it does not know if a leading `0` was present, it only parses it to its internal representation. So yes, your only solution is to keep track of the string yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can read [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#BigDecimal%28java.lang.String%29) the dot devides the IntegerPart from the FractionPart. So in your case the 0 is added as the IntegerPart because u only pass a fractionPart

Comment: Daniel, thanks for the reply. You said I only passed a fractionPart, can you point me to the function which takes both the parts?

Answer (score 1):

Hope this help :)

If it's okay with you can create a subclass for BigDecimal like say:

```
class CustomBigDecimal extends BigDecimal{

String originalValue;

public CustomBigDecimal(String str) {
    super(str);
    originalValue=str;
}

public String toString(){
    return originalValue;

}
}
```

then use it like this:

```
CustomBigDecimal cbd1 = new CustomBigDecimal("0.12");
System.out.println(cbd1);
CustomBigDecimal cbd2 = new CustomBigDecimal(".12");
System.out.println(cbd2);
```

Output:

```
0.12
.12
```

Comment: Hi Lchukka, I have updated my question. Please have a look.

Comment: Edited my Answer too. This should help.

Answer (score -2):

One way is to format the String returned from `toString()` and remove the leading zero manually:

`bd.toString().replaceFirst("^0\\.", ".");`