# hibernate displaying exponential value

Tags: oracle, hibernate

I have inserted value into DB float column using hibernate.The inserted value is 0.00000000000000001. When I did a select from , in SQL plus window, I see that value is inserted and displayed correctly. However when I retrieve the same value using hibernate load method, it displays exponential value. How to avoid this ?

Comment: Please share the code where you are trying to use the value.

Comment: As SQL*Plus shows the correct value the data has obviously been inserted properly into the database, so what you're seeing is a formatting issue in whatever client, tool, or language you're using. Best of luck.

Comment: Contact contact1 = new Contact("babusailesh1117777", "hainatu1@gmail.com", "Vietnam1", "0904277091",new BigDecimal("0.00000000000000001"));
session.persist(contact1);
session.getTransaction().commit();
session.flush();
session.close();
  
session = sessionFactory.openSession();
Contact contact5 = (Contact) session.load(Contact.class, new Integer(2));
System.out.println(contact5.getAmount());

Comment: The getamount method return exponential value

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to print formatted BigDecimal values?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3395825/how-to-print-formatted-bigdecimal-values)