# BigDecimal formats

Tags: java

I have to set up my BigDecimal values at 2 places with different format.

1st One :
If there are trailing zeroes then just have 1 digit after decimal and if not then just do mode as floor

```
eg.
1250.348 -> 1250.34
1250.0000 -> 1250.0
1250.50 -> 1250.5
```

So, I am trying something like this

```
BigDecimal value = new BigDecimal("1250.348");
value = value.setScale(2, RoundingMode.FLOOR); //I get 1250.34 which is proper
```

But it doesnt work for 1250.50 or 1250.000

2nd One :
I just want to remove all zeroes decimal

```
1250.000->1250
1250.50->1250.5
```

Can someone tell me how can I do this ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to print formatted BigDecimal values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3395825/how-to-print-formatted-bigdecimal-values)

Comment: Do you want to actually change the scale of the numbers, or is this used for formatting for display only?

Comment: @Joni For display only

Comment: @JGFMK No, one solution is same as mine, but it doesnt work for all

Answer (score 1):

Use [DecimalFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html). In your first case you want the format pattern `0.0#`.

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("0.0#");
formatter.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.FLOOR);

formatter.format(new BigDecimal("1250.348"));
```

In the second case, you'll want to use format pattern `0.##`.