# How to keep trailing zeros when dividing a BigDecimal

Tags: java, bigdecimal, zero, divide

I have a requirement where I need to divide one `BigDecimal` number by 100 and show the exact amount that comes up without removing trailing zeros. But zeros are getting trimmed by default. How do I prevent that?

```
BigDecimal endDte = new BigDecimal("2609.8200");
BigDecimal startDte = new BigDecimal("100");


BigDecimal finalPerformance = endDte.divide(startDte);
System.out.println(finalPerformance.toString());
```

Output: `26.0982`
Expected: `26.098200`

Comment: As per the javadocs, the resultant scale will be a.scale - b.scale

Comment: This may answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3395825/how-to-print-formatted-bigdecimal-values

Comment: No , it does not help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to print formatted BigDecimal values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3395825/how-to-print-formatted-bigdecimal-values)

Comment: It's just a printing issue, not specific for BigDecimals. All you need her is to format your output  using `DecimalFormat` class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is formatting as those 0 does not add to value. You can use this and you will get desired output.

```java
        BigDecimal endDte = new BigDecimal("2609.8200");
        BigDecimal startDte = new BigDecimal("100");

        BigDecimal finalPerformance = endDte.divide(startDte);
        System.out.printf("%2.6f%n", finalPerformance);
```

Other option if you always want to divide by 100, you can just shift the decimal. When you do that, the precision remains the same. In that case the new code to try is

```java
        BigDecimal endDte = new BigDecimal("2609.8200");
        //BigDecimal startDte = new BigDecimal("100");


        BigDecimal finalPerformance = endDte.movePointLeft(2);
        System.out.println(finalPerformance);
```

Comment: No not working if in case the value is 2609.82001 it is removing 1 from the end.

Comment: What I have done is just the formatting. All I am saying is print 6 decimal place.

Comment: movePointLeft is what I was looking for. Thanks !