# BigDecimal. multiply() and divide() methods return hexadecimal number. Why?

Tags: java, bigdecimal

Here is my code:

```
public class Test1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BigDecimal wallet = new BigDecimal("0.0");
        BigDecimal productPrice = new BigDecimal("0.01");

        for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
            wallet = wallet.multiply(productPrice);
        }
        System.out.println(wallet);
    }
}
```

**Result: 0E-11** 
I have a question. Why am I getting the result in the hexadecimal number system and not in decimal? Like this: 2.45

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your case, the method [`toString`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#toString()) is used which will use an exponent field if needed.

You can use [`toPlainString`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#toPlainString()) if you do not want a string representation with an exponent field.

```
System.out.println(wallet.toPlainString());
```

Answer (score 6):

That's not a hexadecimal, it's [the scientific notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation) as evaluated by the [`toString()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigDecimal.html#toString()) method:

> Returns the string representation of this `BigDecimal`, using scientific notation if an exponent is needed.

The `E` letter denotes the exponent of the number.

In general if you want to format a decimal number, you can use [`java.text.DecimalFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/DecimalFormat.html).

Comment: Thank you for your response! Is there any way to transform this number to decimal form?

Comment: @Ansar1437 Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3395825/how-to-print-formatted-bigdecimal-values and the DecimalFormat class.